# Ways to access directories with long path names under Windows

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

I have a NTFS partition shared between Ubuntu 10.10 and Windows 7, where I have created some directories with long path names under Ubuntu, which cannot be accessed by Windows. I wonder if there is some way that I can access these directories under Windows?

For example, for a directory with a long path name not accessible under Windows, is it possible to create a symbolic link with a much shorter path name under Ubuntu, and make the link accessible under Windows, so that accessing the link is equivalent to accessing the original directory with the long path name?

Answer (score 2):

Strange. How long is this file name? NTFS file path maximum is 32K. I highly doubt your file path is that long.

More than likely you are talking about the 260 path limit in the console. You can get around that by changing your working directory(cd) part of the way to your destination.  Then doing another `cd`.

**edit**

> (1)What do you mean by "NTFS file path maximum is 32K"? I mean the length of a path name has >limit in Windows.

NTFS is the file system Windows primarily uses.  The file system allows file path lengths to be 32K, as in 32,000-ish characters.  So I'm assuming you are running into the 255 file limit, which is kinda rare these days. Unless your programs are using the older APIs. To solve this issue, you have to be more specific with your problem.  What program spits out the error and when?

> (2)Can you say more about how "changing your working directory(cd) part of the way to your >destination. Then doing another cd"exactly is? I don't know how to do it.

`cd` is the command to change the working directory.  Typically I ran into the 260 max path with batch files or console programs.  You can work around the problem by using `cd` to change the current directory closer to your target.

For example, if you are targeting a folder under   **\A\Really\Friggin\Long\and\Pain\in\the\butt\folder\in\a\path\this\long\for\some\acursed\reason\and\now\I\am\tired\of\this\insanity**
then you can type `cd \A\Really\Friggin\Long\and\Pain\in\the\butt\folder\` and cut the path short enough to work with.

Again, this may have nothing to do with your problem since we have no idea what "programs" can't access these paths.

Comment: Thanks! (1) What do you mean by "NTFS file path maximum is 32K"? I mean the length of a path name has limit in Windows. (2) Can you say more about how "changing your working directory(cd) part of the way to your destination. Then doing another cd"exactly is? I don't know how to do it.